# regular expression test on list of numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var str = "123456";

if (!(/^\s*\d{6,7}\s*$/.test(str)))
{
    console.log("no");
} else {

    console.log("yes!");
}
```

How to change this regular expression to console.log yes **only** when the length of str is 6, 7 or 10?

Comment: read more about [Regular_Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply try with **OR** ing.

```
^\s*(\d{6,7}|\d{10})\s*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dF0lJ7/4)

Pattern explanation:

```
  ^                        the beginning of the string
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times)
  (                        group and capture to \1:
    \d{6,7}                  digits (0-9) (between 6 and 7 times)
   |                        OR
    \d{10}                   digits (0-9) (10 times)
  )                        end of \1
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times)
  $                        the end of the string
```

[Learn more...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: you are great. Just the difference of non-capturing groups.

Comment: Thanks!  I appreciate the line by line explanation.

Answer (score 5):

Change your regex like below so that it would allow 6 or 7 or 10 digit number with an optional  leading and trailing spaces.

```
^\s*(?:\d{10}|\d{6,7})\s*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nO4kH0/2)

**Code:**

```
> var str = "1234567890";
undefined
> if (!(/^\s*(?:\d{10}|\d{6,7})\s*$/.test(str)))
... {
...  console.log("no");
... } else {
...  console.log("yes!");
... }
yes!
```

**Explanation:**

```
^                        the beginning of the string
\s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                         more times)
(?:                      group, but do not capture:
  \d{10}                   digits (0-9) (10 times)
 |                        OR
  \d{6,7}                  digits (0-9) (between 6 and 7 times)
)                        end of grouping
\s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                         more times)
$                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                         string
```

Comment: you are rock star in regex.